# How do I do a Depth First Search Alphabetically?

Tags: depth-first-search

I was asked the following on a quiz:

List the order of traversal of the above graph when using Depth First Search (DFS) starting from the vertex E.  When you have the option of adding more than one vertex to the stack, add the vertex that comes before the other alphabetically first.[image]

The answer I gave was: EACBD  However, the professor says the correct answer is EADCB... Can someone explain this to me?

I have tried asking him several times already, and each time he brushes me off. 
The tutor I am seeing does not understand ether.  And the videos on youtube seem to contradict my professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put  C - D  into stack in that order (alphabetically).
 Stack works [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO), so when you pop the order is D  -  C, so  the correct answer is EADCB.

Comment: I see.  So the order is based on what is popped, not what enters first.